# jquery plugin default object reliant on other default key?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to make one of my options dependent on another option.

I think it's easiest to explain what I'd like to do in code. So, below is essentially what I'm trying to do --

```
settings = {
  something     : '#something',
  something_else: something + '_else' 
  // I'd like something_else to map to '#something_else' now
}
```

As you can see, I'd like to be able to rely on a previous key/value pair for another default option. Is that possible? If so, how can I go about accomplishing that?

**Note:** I'm getting a *'Reference Error: something is not defined'*

Comment: Need a little more context. It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do and your error - are you asking about that in addition?

Comment: no, i was just giving it for background information. i will add to my question for clarity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't make a self-referentail JavaScript object like that. You'd have to do it in two pieces with something like this:

```
// options is the usual plugin options objects that comes in an argument.
var defaults = {
    something: '#something'
};
var generated = {
    something_else: '_else'
};
options = $.extend({ }, defaults, options);
for(var p in generated) {
    if(!p.hasOwnProperty(p) || p in options)
        continue;
    options[p] = options.something + generated[p];
}
```

You could try this:

```
var defaults = {
    something:      '#something',
    something_else: '#something_else'
};
```

but then you'd have to go through and fix up the `something_else` after merging in the `options` in case they sent in a non-default `something`; during this fix up pass through the `options` you'd have to be sure not to overwrite a non-default `something_else`.

Comment: thank you! i wasn't sure about it, but that makes sense. i had never tried it before, and thought it'd be cool if i could get it to work...